# Is there any option getting ipython command prompt while running flask

Tags: python, tkinter, flask, ipython

Let me try to explain my problem with example now.

Here is sample GUI code with Tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If I run this code in Ipython, I don't get a command prompt when the GUI is visible.
Now if I comment out the line, "root.mainloop()", the code still works in Ipython and I have access to command prompt so that I can inspect data when the code is running.

Now coming to the Flask case,

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

app.run()
```

When I run this application in Ipython, I don't get a command prompt. To access variables while the code is running, I need to stop the flask server.

Is there any option to run the flask server and have access to command prompt?

Thank you

Comment: How about setting breakpoints?

Comment: No, It's not work for me. We need to run the code and get prompt simultaneously.

Comment: You could set up logging and log the vars you want to inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the flask application in separate thread.
try this example:-

```
from flask import Flask                                                         
import thread
data = 'foo'
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return data
def flaskThread():
    app.run()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread.start_new_thread(flaskThread,())
```

run this file in ipython:-
"run -i filename.py"
then you can access the ipython terminal for inspection.

Answer (score 2):

I second @NewWorld and would recommend a debugger. You can inspect the program in an IPython shell with the IPython debugger. Install e.g. with:

```
pip install ipdb
```

Then load the debugger with: `ipdb.set_trace()` like;

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    return 'Hello World!'
```

This will open a IPython command prompt and you can inspect "data while the code is running".

Further information:
Look [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) to get started with ipdb.
 [This site](http://georgejhunt.com/olpc/pydebug/pydebug/ipdb.html) gives a short introduction to available commands once inside the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `flask shell` through `ipython` you can install the following package:

```
pip install flask-shell-ipython
```